# How can I test my socket program in java using 2 virtual machines?

Tags: java, sockets, virtual

I wrote a simple socket program in java and I test it using CMD and it works. 
But it is required from me to test the program using 2 virtual boxes

So could you help me and tell me the procedure that i must follow to test my program?

Here is the codes

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1201);
        Socket s = ss.accept();

        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String msgin = "",msgout="";
        while(!msgin.equals("end")) {
            msgin = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msgin);
            msgout = br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(msgout);
            dout.flush();
        }
        s.close();
    }

}
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1201);
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String msgin="",msgout="";
        while(!msgin.equals("end")) {
            msgout = br.readLine();
            dout.writeUTF(msgout);
            msgin = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msgin);
        }
        s.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: `Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1",1201);` change this to the ip of the server vm

Answer (score 0):

You can use [docker](https://www.docker.com/) as VM.
Just run two docker containers for each, client and server.